# error - convert date to showing in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i need convert date to shamsi date

i create a method that convert DateTime to shamsi Date.

when i passing a date to the method i got this error

**The best overloaded method match for 'BentaAccounting.Classes.GenralClasses.FarsiDate.MiladiToShamsi(System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments**

this is the code i am using

the method

```
public static string MiladiToShamsi(DateTime Date)   
      {   
           string Result;   
           PersianCalendar FarsiDate = new PersianCalendar();   
            Result = FarsiDate.GetYear(Date).ToString() + "/" +   
                (FarsiDate.GetMonth(Date) < 10 ? "0" + FarsiDate.GetMonth(Date).ToString() : FarsiDate.GetMonth(Date).ToString()) + "/" +   
                (FarsiDate.GetDayOfMonth(Date) < 10 ? "0" + FarsiDate.GetDayOfMonth(Date).ToString() : FarsiDate.GetDayOfMonth(Date).ToString());   
            return Result;   
        }
```

and view

```
<%: Html.Encode(GenralClasses.FarsiDate.MiladiToShamsi(item.OrderDate) )%>
```

Comment: Hi Ali, I tried your example and it works without exception. May be I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public static string MiladiToShamsi(DateTime Date)   
      {   
           string Result;   
           string Year;
           string Month;
           string Day;
           # string Result, Year, Month, Day I don't know this works or not in asp.net 
           PersianCalendar FarsiDate = new PersianCalendar();   
            Year = FarsiDate.GetYear(Date).ToString();
            Month = (FarsiDate.GetMonth(Date) < 10 ? "0" + FarsiDate.GetMonth(Date).ToString() : FarsiDate.GetMonth(Date).ToString());
            Day = (FarsiDate.GetDayOfMonth(Date) < 10 ? "0" + FarsiDate.GetDayOfMonth(Date).ToString() : FarsiDate.GetDayOfMonth(Date).ToString());
            Result = Year + "/" +   Month   + "/" +   Day  ;   
            return Result;   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you get this exception is - item.OrderDate's type not a DateTime. Maby it's
string or something else.

Comment: NO i am sure that data type of orderDate is DateTime

Comment: This is very strange. I tryed your code in the following way and it works just fine <%: Html.Encode(GenralClasses.FarsiDate.MiladiToShamsi(DateTime.Now) )%> 
Does it works for you?

Comment: No it doesn't works for me.the data type of OrderDate was nvarchar before and i changed it to datetime.